# Python ASCII to binary

Tags: python, binary, ascii

Is there a builtin function that converts ASCII to binary?

For example. converts 'P' to 01010000.

I'm using Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about two together?

```
bin(ord('P'))
# 0b1010000
```

Comment: What does the 0b mean at the start of it

Comment: @Steve that is actually unusable binary, its only 7 characters, "P" is 01010000 but that code is removing the leading 0, outputting only 1010000 which is only 7 characters and therefore unusable

Answer (score 8):

Do you want to convert **bytes** or **characters**?  There's a difference.

If you want bytes, then you can use

```
# Python 2.x
' '.join(bin(ord(x))[2:].zfill(8) for x in u'שלום, עולם!'.encode('UTF-8'))

# Python 3.x
' '.join(bin(x)[2:].zfill(8) for x in 'שלום, עולם!'.encode('UTF-8'))
```

The `bin` function converts an integer to binary.  The `[2:]` strips the leading `0b`.  The `.zfill(8)` pads each byte to 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
bin(reduce(lambda x, y: 256*x+y, (ord(c) for c in "Hello world"), 0))
```

this is for multiple characters