# Python Convert ASCII characters to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert some input ASCII characters into bytes. Such as from 'a' to 01100001.
I have read answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523551/python-ascii-to-binary). But sometimes it gives out 0b10000110 like 9 digits values. I am not sure if that's an error or that's the way it supposes to work. 
 I have made something like this:

```
text = list(input("text: "))

for character in text:
    if character == ' ':
        byt = '00000000'
    else:
        byt = bin(ord(character))
    byt = byt.replace('b', '') #delete the 'b' in the output
    if len(byt) != 8:
        byt = '0' + byt
    print(byt)
```

It worked pretty well with normal characters. But when I entered weird characters like: 'B
It outputs very strangely:

```
001110
00100111
0010000000
01000010
```

I am not very experienced with Python, so I don't know if there is a way that you can write a function or other methods to do this.
I am using Python 3.6
Many thanks

Comment: You don't want *bytes*, you want a *binary representation*. A string consisting of only 0 and 1 characters. The same way that `"42"`is not an integer, it is a string representation of the number.

Comment: binary representation is what I mean. Thanks

Comment: `format(ord(character), '08b')` would produce an 8-character binary representation.

Answer (score 3):

The insight you are looking for is:

```
>>> '{:08b}'.format(121)
'01111001'
>>> '{:08b}'.format(7)
'00000111'
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Martijn Pieters, the builtin `format` function is far superior:

```
>>> format(121, '08b')
'01111001'
>>> format(7, '08b')
'00000111'
```

**UPDATE 2**

Just realized this question was marked as a duplicate. Pieters gave the format answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16926357/831878), and explains how it works in detail.

Comment: Don't use `str.format()` where you can use the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format). Why add the parsing overhead? `format(121, '08b')` produces the same output without Python having to find the placeholder and pulling the formatting instruction out. You have just *one* placeholder and no other text in that template string.

Comment: How did I not know about this builtin function? I thought I knew them all. Wow, thanks!